# Angular - ngui-auto-complete unexpected focus error

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, autofocus

I am building a web application where I used several pages for several purposes. But on one of the pages, `ngui-auto-complete` shows an unexpected focus problem. Though I did not set any focus event for this `ngui-auto-complete`, it still remains focused after the content is initiated.

It is a child page where I am redirecting from a parent page on clicking a button. On this child page, there are some `input` fields, some `ngui-auto-complete`, and a `p-calendar` at the top section of the page. Under this section, I put a `p-table` to get details aginst the above section. The below `p-table` contains two `input` fields and two `ngui-auto-completes`. And the problem comes here. The last `ngui-auto-complete` always remains focused though I did not set any focus event for it. If I comment out the last ngui-auto-complete, then the other one remains focused. If I comment out another one also, then the focus problem remains no longer. I searched google for a solution but no satisfactory solution was found. That's why I am asking here in the hope of having a solution.

**For some terms and conditions I can't provide my code. It is forbidden to share any codes. So sorry for that**

But the design is something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by using `[re-focus-after-select]="false"`. Found this solution after posting this question.